# Phrase For Inside the Bell Curve

Tags: phrases

I asked one of my friends what a *hipster* was the other day as it's becoming a popular term and he replied:

> "It's a person who's **inside 95% of the bell curve** while claiming they're an outlier."

I'm curious what the proper English phrase for *inside 95% of the bell curve* is?

Comment: I think that is implying that a hipster is someone who conforms to a high degree with everyone else (in other words, a conformist) but *thinks* they're a non-conformist.

Comment: I'd say it's a mathematical expression, and you probably wouldn't want to hear it. 95% of the area under the normal distribution curve lies within 1.96 standard deviations of the mean.

Comment: @KristinaLopez LOL, this has nothing to do with hipsters - hipster was an example of how someone is using an expression/phrase.  I'm asking about the expression/phrase.

Comment: Well, your question used "hipster".  I connected that contextually to the "inside 95% of the bell curve" to come up with ***conformist*** - which is another way to describe a person inside 95% of the bell curve.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is such a technical issue of statistics, the bell curve is more jargon than common usage.

There is , therefore, no real proper English phrase.

I'm almost tempted to say that "within 3 standard deviations of the mean" is as common as any other usage.  But only because that would be the most common way of putting it in the jargon.

Comment: So `within 3 standard deviations of the mean, but thinks they're an outlier`.  That does have a ring to it.